# PKIXNameConstraintValidatorException: DNS is not from a permitted subtree

Tags: java, ssl, https, bouncycastle

I am loading one of the ssl certificate from a .crt file to access one resource. But when I make the call to that intranet resource. I get following exception.  Can someone suggest how to overcome this problem?  Also can I disable a DNS check

```
...
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Subtree check for certificate subject alternative name failed.
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:362)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:270)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1496)
    ... 81 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Subtree check for certificate subject alternative name failed.
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.RFC3280CertPathUtilities.processCertBC(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:357)
    ... 87 more
Caused by: org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.PKIXNameConstraintValidatorException: DNS is not from a permitted subtree.
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.PKIXNameConstraintValidator.checkPermittedDNS(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.PKIXNameConstraintValidator.checkPermitted(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: The CA that issued the cert used by the server is broken and violating standards. For an intranet resource that you need a special cert to trust, this is likely an inhouse CA. Best have the CA fixed, or have the server use a different CA that isn't broken. You can't disable this check selectively; you _can_ disable cert checking _completely_ with a dummy `TrustManager` (shown and even recommended in many Stack Qs and As) if your network is completely and permanently secure (which it never is) or all your data is unimportant and worthless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer to this problem, sharing if it saves time for anybody else.
What is been observed is that in some cases only CA root certificate is not sufficient. But when other intermediate certs are also loaded then this issue didnt occur. So basically the whole chain certificates were needed to overcome this problem. As a combination of bouncy castle library upgrade and including whole chain certs worked for me.